# Changing vector value causing seg fault

Tags: c++, pointers, boolean

I am working on a school project for graphs and here I am doing a depth first search down the tree.

```
void wdigraph::depth_first(int v) const {
    static int firstv = -1;
    static bool *visited = NULL;

    if (firstv == -1) {
            firstv = v;
            vector<bool> visited(size);
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    visited[i] = false;
                    cout << visited[i] << endl;
            }
    }
    cout << label[v];
  visited[v] = true;
```

> //    visited[0] = true;

The first input value to the function is 0 (v = 0) and it crashes with that.  size = 5.  As you can see at the end of the code, I have tried to set visited to true manually with the same seg fault.  When I remove all attempts to change visited, the program runs how it should normally without a seg fault.

Any ideas why this can't be modified?  Also, there is more code but I have decided not to provide it unless necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different variables named `visited` in your code. Inside the `if` condition, `visited` is a vector, but outside this block, on the last line:

```
visited[v] = true;
```

`visited` refers to the `bool *visited = NULL` defined at the beginning of your code. The segfault occurs because you're trying to dereference a null pointer.